# ReactJs: Invalid DOM property `classname` error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am parsing a HTML string to React.js and render it as HTML element using "ReactHtmlParser" suggested in that previous post [React.js: Raw HTML string does not gets recognized as HTML elements from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52556583/react-js-raw-html-string-does-not-gets-recognized-as-html-elements-from-node-js). 
Now, I am trying add Bootstrap style attribute on it, by doing the following:

```
app.get('/myCart', (req, res) => {
  var data;
  var htmlString ="";
  var total = 0;

  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("cart");
    dbo.collection("items").find().toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("here")
      data = result
      for(let item of data){
        htmlString += "<div className=\"row\"><div className=\"col\">" + item.desc + "</div>" + "<div className=\"col\">" + item.price + "</div></div>"
        total += item.price
      }
      console.log("total is" + total)
      htmlString +="<div className=\"row\"><div>" + total + "</div><div>"
      console.log(htmlString)
      res.send({express: htmlString})
      db.close();
    });
  });
```

My render method:

```
render(){
    console.log(this.state.cartData)
    return(
        <div className="col">
            <div>{ReactHtmlParser(this.state.cartData)}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

As you can see, it is actually `className` not `classname`. However, when I render it to front-end, it got error saying that `Invalid DOM property classname. Did you mean className`

I really have no idea because I only put className as attribute.  Does it have to do with ReactHtmlParser?

Comment: what if you change it to `class` ?

Comment: It would be wrong because react use className as its default attribute

Comment: just try out `class` ... I got the feeling that it might work

Comment: its HTML string so you just write there class instead of className

Comment: How are you fetching the code from the backend?

Comment: You know, the post you linked to suggests to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. this is [react's API to set html strings](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

Comment: @JonasWilms it worked. This question makes me feel dumb. Do you want to post the comment the answer so i can close this question?

Comment: @Sagivb.g i used the suggestion from one of the comment

Comment: @SpencerOvetsky I still think it is just how you are fetching the html, thinking maybe you set it to say it was HTML and it parses your string as HTML block which normalizes your attributes. If you set it to be text and not HTML it might keep the attribute camelCased correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TheReactHTMLParser parses HTML, so you have to use the HTML `class` property.

If you use `className`, the parser will lowercase the properties as html props are always lowercase, resulting in the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this document (https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html), `React DOM` is not `HTML DOM` will have some difference in attribute name like `className` in React DOM vs `class` in HTML DOME

> All Supported HTML Attributes As of React 16, any standard or custom
>   DOM attributes are fully supported.
>
> React has always provided a JavaScript-centric API to the DOM. Since
>   React components often take both custom and DOM-related props, React
>   uses the camelCase convention just like the DOM APIs:
>
> ```
> <div tabIndex="-1" />      // Just like node.tabIndex DOM API
> <div className="Button" /> // Just like node.className DOM API
> <input readOnly={true} />  // Just like node.readOnly DOM API
> ```
>
> These props work similarly to the corresponding HTML attributes, with
>   the exception of the special cases documented above.
>
> Some of the DOM attributes supported by React include:
>
> ```
> accept acceptCharset accessKey action allowFullScreen alt async autoComplete
> autoFocus autoPlay capture cellPadding cellSpacing challenge charSet checked
> cite classID className colSpan cols content contentEditable contextMenu controls
> controlsList coords crossOrigin data dateTime default defer dir disabled
> download draggable encType form formAction formEncType formMethod formNoValidate
> formTarget frameBorder headers height hidden high href hrefLang htmlFor
> httpEquiv icon id inputMode integrity is keyParams keyType kind label lang list
> loop low manifest marginHeight marginWidth max maxLength media mediaGroup method
> min minLength multiple muted name noValidate nonce open optimum pattern
> placeholder poster preload profile radioGroup readOnly rel required reversed
> role rowSpan rows sandbox scope scoped scrolling seamless selected shape size
> sizes span spellCheck src srcDoc srcLang srcSet start step style summary
> tabIndex target title type useMap value width wmode wrap
> ```
>
> Similarly, all SVG attributes are fully supported:
>
> ```
> accentHeight accumulate additive alignmentBaseline allowReorder alphabetic
> amplitude arabicForm ascent attributeName attributeType autoReverse azimuth
> baseFrequency baseProfile baselineShift bbox begin bias by calcMode capHeight
> clip clipPath clipPathUnits clipRule colorInterpolation
> colorInterpolationFilters colorProfile colorRendering contentScriptType
> contentStyleType cursor cx cy d decelerate descent diffuseConstant direction
> display divisor dominantBaseline dur dx dy edgeMode elevation enableBackground
> end exponent externalResourcesRequired fill fillOpacity fillRule filter
> filterRes filterUnits floodColor floodOpacity focusable fontFamily fontSize
> fontSizeAdjust fontStretch fontStyle fontVariant fontWeight format from fx fy
> g1 g2 glyphName glyphOrientationHorizontal glyphOrientationVertical glyphRef
> gradientTransform gradientUnits hanging horizAdvX horizOriginX ideographic
> imageRendering in in2 intercept k k1 k2 k3 k4 kernelMatrix kernelUnitLength
> kerning keyPoints keySplines keyTimes lengthAdjust letterSpacing lightingColor
> limitingConeAngle local markerEnd markerHeight markerMid markerStart
> markerUnits markerWidth mask maskContentUnits maskUnits mathematical mode
> numOctaves offset opacity operator order orient orientation origin overflow
> overlinePosition overlineThickness paintOrder panose1 pathLength
> patternContentUnits patternTransform patternUnits pointerEvents points
> pointsAtX pointsAtY pointsAtZ preserveAlpha preserveAspectRatio primitiveUnits
> r radius refX refY renderingIntent repeatCount repeatDur requiredExtensions
> requiredFeatures restart result rotate rx ry scale seed shapeRendering slope
> spacing specularConstant specularExponent speed spreadMethod startOffset
> stdDeviation stemh stemv stitchTiles stopColor stopOpacity
> strikethroughPosition strikethroughThickness string stroke strokeDasharray
> strokeDashoffset strokeLinecap strokeLinejoin strokeMiterlimit strokeOpacity
> strokeWidth surfaceScale systemLanguage tableValues targetX targetY textAnchor
> textDecoration textLength textRendering to transform u1 u2 underlinePosition
> underlineThickness unicode unicodeBidi unicodeRange unitsPerEm vAlphabetic
> vHanging vIdeographic vMathematical values vectorEffect version vertAdvY
> vertOriginX vertOriginY viewBox viewTarget visibility widths wordSpacing
> writingMode x x1 x2 xChannelSelector xHeight xlinkActuate xlinkArcrole
> xlinkHref xlinkRole xlinkShow xlinkTitle xlinkType xmlns xmlnsXlink xmlBase
> xmlLang xmlSpace y y1 y2 yChannelSelector z zoomAndPan
> ```