# React html parser not working with nexjts

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am fetching data from api(created in php),There is description field (data saved by ckeditor)

In my db/api data is saving in following format

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Hello admin &lt;em&gt;Lorem Ipsum dummy text&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

And i am using "ReactHtmlParser" for display blog content in web page

```
{ReactHtmlParser(post.description)}
```

But its showing me data in following format,how can i solve this ?

```
<p><strong>Hello admin <em>Lorem Ipsum dummy text</em></strong></p>
```

My expected output is "
**Hello admin** *Lorem Ipsum dummy text* "

Comment: take a look at this  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643424/how-to-parse-html-to-react-component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse html to React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643424/how-to-parse-html-to-react-component)

Comment: @jondoe: i tried but not working for me

Comment: @Tom: as i mentioned its giving me "<p><strong>Hello admin <em>Lorem Ipsum dummy text</em></strong></p>" in my web but whenever i use this code into "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" then its working fine

Comment: How are you using it in your React component? Can you add the component code?